# PrimeNG Menu is not clickable

Tags: angular, primeng

I have my menu configured

TS

```
 this.items = [
          {
            label: "Home",
            icon: "pi pi-home",
            command: () => this.onHome(),
            routerLink: ["/home"]
          },
          { label: "Business Owner", icon: "pi pi-user", command: (event) => { this.onHome(); }  },
          { label: "Check-ins", icon: "pi pi-check", routerLink: ["/faq"] },
          { label: "FAQ", icon: "pi pi-question-circle", routerLink: ["/faq"] },
          {
            label: "Sign Up/Login",
            icon: "pi pi-user",
            routerLink: ["/login"]
          },
          {
            // label: "Language",
            icon: "pi pi-comment",
            items: [
              { label: "Malay", command: () => this.onSwitchLang("ms") },
              { label: "English", command: () => this.onSwitchLang("en") },
              { label: "中文", command: () => this.onSwitchLang("zh-cn") }
            ]
          },
          { label: "CVR", icon: "pi pi-star-o", routerLink: ["/cover"] }
        ];
```

Template & Layout
[image]
I built a responsive header (the header layout become a hamburger menu). But all the routerLink, onclick (command()) are not functioning.

When i switch to web layout, all the top links are workable
[image]
How to make both mobile and web top menu respond to click and routerLink event?

updates:
I noticed the isuse caused by the sub item "language"

```
  {
    // label: "Language",
    icon: "pi pi-comment",
    items: [
      { label: "Malay", command: () => this.onSwitchLang("ms") },
      { label: "English", command: () => this.onSwitchLang("en") },
      { label: "中文", command: () => this.onSwitchLang("zh-cn") }
    ]
  },
```

Once it's removed, the routerLink and command can work correctly. How could i make both item and sub-item command-able/link-able?

Comment: add a workable fiddle

Comment: i m using StackBlitz. you may check header component
https://stackblitz.com/edit/prime-lout-yb7hka?file=src%2Fapp%2Fcomponents%2Fheader%2Fheader.component.ts

make the screen small enough and u can get the hamburger icon. Then u can see the dropdown, but they became not click-able

Comment: I have checked the code, and its working fine, on click hamburger menu is showing

Comment: @AtulRajput, yes, shorten the width until the hamburger icon show. The menu will pop up. But when you try "Home", "Business Owner"...  those links are not clickable.

Comment: Oh. Let me check again

Comment: I checked your code again and the problem is with your menu package , I the desktop menu has anchor in it but the mobile menu does not, its creating the different menu for desktop and mobile, check your plugin documentation once

Comment: the TS code is used by both p-menu and p-menubar. By right both are working perfectly until i put the "sub-item" (language) branch and everything start break (shared in my original post). Hence, i forced to replaced p-menu with p-slidemenu.